# Sitecore Content Search: do I have to specify the language?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm using `IProviderSearchContext` to search for a specific item in Sitecore 8.1 (Lucene Search) and I get two versions of each item (en, ar).
My question is: do I have to specifiy: `item.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name` for every query or is there a way to make the `IProviderSearchContext` get data according to the language in the current Sitecore context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing providers are very rudimentary about indexing. 
With normal querying with Sitecore.Data.Item your results are automatically filtered by the context language and latest item version, no such filtering occurs when you are using indexing.
You will receive all versions and all languages unless you specify on Linq query.

With indexing is mandatory to use:  item.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name if you want to filter results on current language. 
To use above filtering you also need to inherit your ResultItem class from SearchResultItem. Otherwise your ResultItem need to add a new index field to your class like above one:

```
  [IndexField(“_language”)]
  public string Language { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you this makes sense. However I don't need to add the `Language` field because it already exists in the `SearchResultItem` class.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm down voting this as the correct answer, because it not the fully correct way to implement language specific search.  I believe a previous developer used this logic and now we ran into issues with searching on fr-FR.  The answer to use CultureExecutionContext works fully.

Answer (score 3):

You can also pass in a `CultureExecutionContext` to your query which will limit the results by language.

```
var culture = Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo;

var queryable = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>(new CultureExecutionContext(culture));
```

There is some more information about this in [this](http://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/04/14/sitecore-contentsearch-language-based-search/) post

Comment: I had a quick look at the article and your code sample and applied it like this: `var query = context.GetQueryable<BranchLocationViewModel>(new CultureExecutionContext(Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo)).Where(predicate).ToList();` But it returned two versions... This is strange.

Comment: Could be config related, have a look at this post to see how it hangs together -http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/08/Execution-Contexts-Explained.aspx